# configurable namespace value of XmlRootElement

Tags: web-services, jaxb, wsdl, jax-ws

I have spent 2 days to solve my problem and have no idea anymore about it.
here I have a class name with **InquiryClient** and the namespace set hardcoded into **http://localhost:8080/serverSide**,

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="InquiryClientResponse", namespace="http://localhost:8080/serverSide")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class InquiryClient {
         public String ClientName;
    }
```

What do I need to do is just make **namespace** attribute configurable, not harcoded...
I've tried to set the XmlSchema from package-info level, and its running well also but neither harcoded.

I've a parameter taken from config.properties
wsdl.url = http://localhost:8080/serverSide

what if I use the wsdl.url to set in that package-info or in @XmlRootElement attribute value... how do I get them?

it would be pleasure whoever would give me the way out...